# Story identification, meta-tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, site-recommendation

I was wondering which SE site would be best to ask about hardly hearable (for me) quote from (probably) some movie, that I have encountered on some YT clip [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBYizq82NTI#t=66).

Movies? Story-identification tag has 3 entries.
Sci-Fi? Story-identification reaching 5k, yet nothing audible indicates it is related to Sci-fi.
Perhaps Music?

Or perhaps we could use meta-tag(s) that filters particular SE site, but is common across multiple SE sites. Or maybe another SE site where additional points could be awarded for directing flow of questions into proper categories, sites? Or without points, just it could be voted inside which group/site/tags fit best.

Comment: possibly yes, but - expanding question, how should i even know it is from a movie? It is long shot, true but some bits from public speech might be sometimes looked for.

Comment: If you don't even know it's from a movie or not then you have no question to ask really. Search Google for the parts of the story you know.

Comment: Could you look back at both the Question Title and Exposition, strain out what doesn't matter and re-phrase the useful kernel?

Answer (score 7):

The main problem seems to be, though, that you don't really seem to know where that quote is from at all. It could be a movie, it could be a song, it could be some interview, it could just be some arbitrary YouTube blabber.

This not only makes it hard to guess on which site to ask, it also makes it not a particulalry good question on the respective site you chose to ask it on, since for example [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com) doesn’t accept story identification at all. Likewise, [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com) currently rules identification questions completely off-topic.

So while that question might go borderline through on some site with a bit of luck, it does not really seem to be a particularly good fit for any of the SE sites in general.

<sub>You might find some success [outside of SE](http://www.quodb.com/), though.</sub>

Comment: This quote I was referring to in this question had found successful solution [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34483/identify-movie-only-by-quote-heard-in-yt-clip), but generally - i agree it does not *currently* fit.